# Drop-in dependency migration from bouncycastle jdk16 to jdk15on

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Bouncycastle provider version 1.46 was released with two packages: `bcprov-jdk16` and `bcprov-jdk15on`.  This was the last release for the `bcprov-jdk16` package in favor of `bcprov-jdk15on`.

Is migration from `bcprov-jdk16` to `bcprov-jdk15on` a drop-in zero change migration, or do functional changes exist between the packages?

Comment: That appears to be a rerelease of some kind, not the original release. My archived copy of crypto-146.tar.gz from 2011-02 has only the jdk1[3-6] files, and BC's FTP site shows those files with that date but the jdk15on files dated 2012-03, over a year later. Since they are presumably the same source I'd expect them to be compatible, but I haven't tested. There definitely were API changes between 1.46 and 1.47; I remember that event with some pain.

Comment: This should really be asked at the bouncy castle dev mailing list instead. You'll get more authoritative answers there. If you do please report back and create an answer here!